# After updating several jenkins plugins the service does not work

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins requested the update of several plugins and I updated them, but when I restarted it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.GlobalCredentialMigrator.lambda$migrate$0(GlobalCredentialMigrator.java:56)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:469)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.GlobalCredentialMigrator.migrate(GlobalCredentialMigrator.java:57)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarInstallation.migrateTokenToCredential(SonarInstallation.java:250)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarGlobalConfiguration.migrateCredentials(SonarGlobalConfiguration.java:122)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1095)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1129)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:936)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

I was reading about this problem and the solution is to remove the updated plugins located at : `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`

Initially I removed the sonar plugin (it is the one that shows the error), I restarted the server but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already managed to fix it.

Every time the plugins are updated the system automatically renames the previous version as `plugin.bak` so what I did was delete the *plugin.jpi* file and restore the `.bak` by changing its extension to `.jpi`

Comment: You also want to remove the unpacked jar. It's usually in the same plugins dir, in a dir matching the plugin name.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get a Jenkins server back up and running. It refused to restart after updating a bunch of plugins.